# Coldfusion Looping Data Into Multiple Columns and Rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, sql, coldfusion

So heres my problem, I am pulling from a database into my website. My keys/attributes (columns) in my database that need to display are PostedDate, DataImage, and Source. I want them to output as one div with the posteddate on the top the image in the middle and the source on the bottom, which I got to do. However, I need them to loop over 3 columns and create a new row every 3 columns so that it is separated and not just one big column or row.

so it would be like this [PostedDate, Image, Source] [PostedDate, Image, Source] etc. 3 columns over multiple rows

This is what I'm trying to get it to look like :

[image]

This is my current code but when I refresh the webpage it gives me a 404 or 500 error :

```
        <!--- set the number of colums you wish to have --->
<cfset cols = 3> 
<cfset totalRows = ceiling(UIData.RecordCount / cols)>
<cfset output = 1>
<table width = "100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing= "2">            
<cfloop from = "1" to = "#totalRows#" index = "thisRow">
<tr>
    <cfloop from = "1" to = "#cols#" index = "thisCol">

    <td width = "<cfoutput>#numberformat((100/cols), 99)#</cfoutput>%" align="center" nowrap style = "border: 1px solid #ccc;">

        <cfif output != UIData.recordCount>
            <cfoutput> 
            <div> <font style="font-size: .8em; line-height: .6em; padding-bottom: .8em;"><strong> #PostedDate# </strong></font> </div>
         <div> <img src="http://www.iowalum.com/uidata/images/#DataImage#" alt="" width="99%" height="264" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;" /> </div>
         <div id ="text"> #Source# </div> </cfoutput>
        <cfelse>
        <!--- use <br> to display an empty cell --->
            <br>
        </cfif>
        <!--- increment counter to the next record in this example if we started on the first cell of the first row it would be 1(a), then 4(d), then 7(g) and so on if this was the firs cell on the second row it would be 2(b), 5(e), 8(h), continue... --->
        <cfset output = output + totalRows>
    </td>
    </cfloop>
    <!--- this little bit tells where to start the next row. if we just finished the first row output would be 2(b) --->
    <cfset output = thisRow + 1>
</tr>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be simpler.

```
<cfset ItemsPerRow = 3>     
<tr>
<cfoutput query="your query">
<td>#output something#    </td>
<cfif currentrow mod ItemsPerRow is 0>
</tr><tr>
<cfelseif currentrow is recordcount>
</tr>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
<tr>
```

Comment: Wow thank you!! I noticed on my code I forgot to put the cf query name and it was close but slightly off.